# Lazy evaluation on slow Boolean functions (optimization)

Tags: optimization, program-optimization

[Short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is a straight forward subject for lazy evaluation on Boolean expressions, I noted that two factors could be useful in ordering Boolean functions to improve run-time. But this is applicable in a very particular hypothesis:

1. Knowing a percentage of positive (hence negative) result of a function. This is followed by a very illustrative example.
2. Knowing execution run-time of the function on data (knowing size of data can be a hint).

My case is easy to understand. Here is a description:

Let's say `F` is a Boolean function that scores **sentiment** and returns `-1 or 1`. I've been doing some improvements to predict sentiment scores on big arrays of text, and I can calculate How much is likely a function will return 1 (**probability withing a tolerated error range**) lets call it `P(f) = Pf` (probability of being positive)

We have also an estimation of **execution time** since data to be analysed is measurable. lets call it `T(f) = Tf`
We define **positiveness speed** as follows:

```
PS (f) =  Pf  / Tf
```

Let `Lazy` be a function which takes a Boolean expression, and gives the best ordering of functions for run-time based on PS scores.

```
Lazy (&, f1, f2, …, fn) = and_Order (f1, f2, …, fn)
```

Where `and_Order` is an ascending order of positiveness speed.

---

```
Lazy (or, f1, f2, …, fn) = or_Order(f1, f2, …, fn)
```

Where `or_Order` is a descending order if positiveness speed.

Obviously this is a high level optimization and not a compiler task. Is this an established study? How is this practical in cases other than sentiment analysis? Is the PS(F) even correctly representing what it should be representing?

Comment: Note that in the & case more complex functions are evaluated first, which is probably not the desired behavior.  Perhaps a better fit would be evaluating by decreasing order in $\frac{1-P_f}{T_f}$. In any case, I don't know whether this has been studied, but this sounds interesting.